# Oracle 11g - optimize WHERE IS NOT NULL and IS NULL

Tags: database, oracle, optimization, oracle11g, null

I have a question about query optimization for a statement which uses `is null` and `is not null` in the WHERE clause.

For example, I have the following query :

```
select name, firstname, adresse1, adresse2, town
from users u, adresses a
where u.user_id = a.user_id
and ((a.user_id is null)
or a.user_id is not null and a.adresse_type = 1))
```

How is it possible to avoid full table scan and use an index to optimize the query ?

Thanks

Comment: You WHERE condition looks quite generic. How many rows does this query return in relation to amount of all rows? Using an index makes only sense when the (expected) number of rows is small in relation to all rows. Otherwise a full table scan might be faster.

Comment: If `a.user_id is null` how do you expect to join `adresses` to `users`???

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the where clause like this. Your current where clause looks ambiguous without braces.

I am assuming you want all records where user id is null. And if Userid is not null, you want records where adresse_type is 1.

```
select name, firstname, adresse1, adresse2, town
from users u
inner join
adresses a
on u.user_id = a.user_id
and not (
    a.user_id is not null 
and a.adresse_type <> 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can as it stands.
For a start, this won't find anything
`where u.user_id = a.user_id` when `a.user_id is null`
rendering the rest of your `while` irrelevant for those.

Oracle does not index `NULL` columns so `user_id is null` can't be satisfied any other way than a table scan.  You can probably build a calculated column on `user_id` with some sentinel value for `NULL` and build an index on that or just build a function-based index that does the same (replaces null with some other value).

Comment: That is not fully true, when you use Bitmap-Index then also NULL values are indexed.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - True but bitmap indexes are an edge case. Most OLTP databases, which is still most databases, probably don't have a single bitmap index.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit yeah sure, but you wouldn't put a bitmap index on anything like a user id would you?

Comment: No, most likely this would not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure your query is correct, but remaining to the question, as far as I know you can use null value in index, but you have to add another column/value to the index and this column/value should not be NULL.  For example, you can try

```
create index addresses_idx01 on addresses (user_id, 1);
```

That said, I think your question is not too clear and the index is not relevant (assuming user_id can't be NULL in both tables). 
As far as I know your query should be equivalent to:

```
SELECT NAME, FIRSTNAME, ADRESSE1, ADRESSE2, TOWN
FROM USERS U
INNER JOIN ADRESSES A ON U.USER_ID = A.USER_ID
WHERE  /* A.USER_ID IS NULL
        OR A.USER_ID IS NOT NULL AND */ A.ADRESSE_TYPE = 1
```

I think that the part between /* and */ should be useless.

Maybe you would want to write:

```
SELECT NAME, FIRSTNAME, ADRESSE1, ADRESSE2, TOWN
FROM USERS U
LEFT JOIN ADRESSES A ON U.USER_ID = A.USER_ID
WHERE  A.USER_ID IS NULL
        OR /*A.USER_ID IS NOT NULL AND */ A.ADRESSE_TYPE = 1
```

Again, the part between /* and */ should be useless.

Comment: It was just to show the use of NULL in index as asked.  But you should read the rest of the answer too, please...

Comment: we could speak for long time about question interpretation... I think one of the important thing to remember on sites like stackoverflow, or more generally too, should be that nobody feel himself a "teacher" as role, but that everyone could learn from others (for this reason I try to avoid to give negative votes, or comment other answers in a negative way).

Comment: I still disagree with you, for both your comments.  I meant "teacher" as role (it was quoted for this).  Anyway, I am not "stinged".  There are things to understand that do not belong to StackOverflow only and you or nobody can say "I am StackOverflow", having 1.000.000 of reputation or more.  Bye.

Answer (score -1):

> "How is it possible to avoid full table scan and use an index to optimize the query ?"

There are no filters on USERS table so a full table scan is the only access path for that table.

You have an inner join to ADRESSES table on `a.user_id = u.user_id` so `a.user_id is null` will never be true in this query. Thus the question becomes is it worth using an index to get this join? Unless you have many more addresses than users (say twenty times more) then no. A full table scan on ADRESSES and a hash join is probably the best path.

If you do have that multiplicity of addesses, then you could derive value from an index on `adresses(user_id, adresse_type)`. Before building such an index you should be certain that you run the query often enough to justify the overhead of maintaining the index.

But all this is guessing. Performance tuning is a matter of metrics, and it's pointless to advise on optimization without knowing the pertinent metrics regarding data volumes and skew.

The key point is, full table scans are often the most efficient way of accessing sets of data. Using an index is not necessarily an optimization.

---

Finally, maybe you should be using an OUTER JOIN in your query:

```
select u.name, u.firstname, a.adresse1, a.adresse2, a.town
from users u
     left join adresses a
on u.user_id = a.user_id
where (a.user_id is null
      or (a.user_id is not null and a.adresse_type = 1))
```

This doesn't affect the performance but it would produce a different result set, one which fits the apparent intention of your code.